# How much reflected light in a Lambertian tube\cylinder from a source at one end hits a tilted rectangle at the other end?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics, geometry

I was doing an experiment that involved determining the relationship between the voltage across a photovoltaic cell and the power of light incident upon it. It involved a lamp, a 1-meter tube made of black poster paper that encircled its shade, and a photovoltaic cell at end of the tube looking like this:
[image: My setup]

The way I've drawn it doesn't make this clear, but the poster paper completely wraps around the shade of the lamp, so no light escapes. My problem is this: some of the light hitting the paper is reflecting off, and the amount of reflected light hitting the cell depends on the angle at which the cell is turned. The image below illustrates this:
[[image: What the problem looks like. The tube has a diameter of <span class=]$d$, a radius of $r$, a length of $l$, and has its opening a distance of $D$ away from the center of the cell." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsy3y.png)

I am assuming that this tube is a Lambertian surface, so the radiance of light reflected from area $dA$ is proportional to $\cos(\alpha)$. The cell is rotated at an angle $\theta$ in a single plane away from the normal, and it subtends a solid angle of $\omega$ relative to $dA$. $dA$ subtends an angle of $d\Omega$ relative to the light source. I have been expressing $dA$ in terms of the two angles $\varphi$ and $\gamma$. To cover the entire tube, $0\leq\varphi\leq2\pi$ and $0\leq\gamma\leq\arctan(\frac lr)$. In general, I am looking for a function of $\gamma$ and $\varphi$ that can be integrated over the cylinder to yield the total reflected light upon the cell:
$$Total Reflected Light = \int_{\varphi=0}^{\varphi=2\pi}\int_{\gamma=0}^{\gamma=\arctan(\frac lr)}f(\varphi, \gamma) d\varphi d\gamma$$

I have attempted a solution, but the result is absolutely horrendous. **It begins here, and it ends at the bold text for those who do not wish to read it.**

The general, less intimidating form of the equation for light reflected onto the cell from $dA$ is as follows:

$$\int (I_{max}\cos(\alpha))(\omega)dA$$

where $I_{max}$ is the maximum radiance of light for the Lambertian surface (along the normal). The problem is that every single term is dependent on $\varphi$ and $\gamma% in its own way:

- $dA$ is approximately a rectangle with side lengths $r[\tan(\gamma+d\gamma)-\tan(\gamma)]$ and $r\tan(\gamma)d\varphi$ based on the drawing below. [[image: Defining <span class=]$dA$ in terms of $d\varphi$ and $d\gamma$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDEYZ.png)
- $I_{max}$, I believe, is proportional to the total incident energy on $dA$ which is proportional to the solid angle $d\Omega$ and the radiance of the light source $I_0$, yielding $I_{max}=kI_0d\Omega$ where $k$ is a constant. $d\Omega$, based on the drawing above, depends on the area of $dA$ perpendicular to the ray from the light source to $dA$. If I'm not mistaken, the solid angle subtended by a $w\times h$ rectangle within a sphere of radius $r$ is $\sqrt{\frac{wh}{(w^2+4r^2)(h^2+4r^2)}}$, so $d\Omega$ becomes the following monstrosity:

$$d\Omega=\sqrt{\frac{[r(\tan(\gamma+d\gamma)-\tan(\gamma))][\sin(\beta)(r\tan(\gamma)d\varphi)]}{[(r(\tan(\gamma+d\gamma)-\tan(\gamma)))^2+4(\frac r{\cos(\gamma)})^2][(\sin(\beta)(r\tan(\gamma)d\varphi))^2+4(\frac r{\cos(\gamma)})^2]}}$$

I really hope there is an easier way to quantify the energy received by $dA$ from the light source, but so far I am stuck with this.

- $\cos(\alpha)$ can be expressed as $\frac {l-r\tan(\gamma)}{\sqrt{r^2+(l-r\tan(\gamma))^2}}$
- $\omega$ is yet another cursed solid angle: the angle subtended by the equivalent perpendicular area of the cell relative to $dA$. The first part involves getting this perpendicular area, which in turn requires getting the angle between the light ray from $dA$ and the center of the cell, as shown below:
  [[image: My physics problem turned into a geometry problem; light from source hitting cell which is at angle <span class=]$\theta$ with currently unknown angle $/varepsilon$ between the light ray and the cell surface normal" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5x4R.png)

For any given pair of $\varphi$ and $\gamma$, there is an angle $\varepsilon$ (or $\angle ABC$). $\cos(\varepsilon)$ multiplied by the actual area of the cell $A_{cell}$ yields the perpendicular area. The ray is drawn at the edge of the tube for convenience, but it could actually hit be hitting any $dA$ within the tube. Thus, $\overline{\rm OA}=r$, $\overline{\rm OC}=l+d-r\tan(\gamma)$, and $\overline{\rm OB}=\overline{\rm OC}\tan(\theta)$. $\varepsilon$ can be found using the Law of Cosines:

$$\varepsilon=\arccos\bigl(\frac{\overline{\rm AC}^2+\overline{\rm BC}^2-\overline{\rm AB}^2}{2(\overline{\rm AC})(\overline{\rm BC})})$$

$$\overline{\rm AC}=\sqrt{r^2+\overline{\rm OC}^2)}, \overline{\rm BC}=\sqrt{r^2+(\overline{\rm BC}\cos(\theta))^2)}, \overline{\rm AB}=\sqrt{r^2+(\overline{\rm DO}+\overline{\rm OB})^2)}=\sqrt{r^2+(r\sin(\varphi)+\overline{\rm OC}\tan(\theta))^2)}$$

The perpendicular area of the cell relative to $dA$ is thus $A_{cell}\cos(\varepsilon)$. Since the equation for a solid angle requires the dimensions of this perpendicular rectangle, I will write the dimensions as $w'\times h'=w\cos(\varepsilon)\times h$.

That covers all of the parts of the problem from my perspective, and I think writing out the full equation (even for just a single $dA$) would be difficult to load. Not to mention, the way I have written the equation does not put $d\varphi$ and $d\gamma$ as terms which are multiplied, so I have no idea how I would even begin to integrate or rearrange the terms of such a terrible equation. There is probably a much more elegant approach, but it is beyond me as of now.

If something is unclear in the diagrams/formulae/explanations, I would be happy to change it so please let me know. Also, I am new to this community and not a professional at all, so I apologize in advance for any rookie mistakes or rules I may be breaking. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Please, have a look at this site policy about homework and homework-like questions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My problem is something unique that only I ran into, and I do not plan on using responses from here in my assignment. I just found this concept interesting and want to learn more about it.

Comment: I think this is a very well posed question with a lot of original work. This is actually quite a tricky problem to calculate and also verify that the answer is correct. An integrating sphere is probably an easier way of doing this experiment, that way you know the angular distribution.